# Blazor Javascript Interop Returns Null

Tags: javascript, c#, blazor, blazor-webassembly, moralis

I have a Javascript function which should (does) return a string. The issue is that the C# part is always null although I've verified the JS function IS returning a string.

Here's the Javascript function:

```
window.get_current_user = () => {
        Moralis.User.currentAsync().then(function (user) {
            var wallet = user.get('ethAddress');
            return wallet;
        });
    }
```

Here's the C# calling it

```
 private async void GetAddress()
 {
    var userAddress = await _js.InvokeAsync<string>("get_current_user");
    _js.InvokeVoidAsync("alert", userAddress);
 }
```

I've used the Chrome Dev Console dev tools to breakpoint at the line in which it returns the value and verified the value is correct and a string.
[image]

I've also placed a breakpoint on the 4th line of the GetAddress function and see that the value of 'userAddress' is indeed null

[image]

Comment: In the dev console - try executing your function - `window.get_current_user()`.  Does that return something?  Do you need a `return` in front of `Moralis...`?

Comment: @jimnkey That's what it was! I forgot the return in front of the initial call. Thank you so much! If you want to answer the question I'll mark it.

Comment: That's ok.  Just glad I could help!

Comment: Also, don't use `async void` here. Make it `async Task`  (and await it).

Answer (score 2):

Do the following, the return should be outside of the second function:

```
window.get_current_user = () => {
var wallet = null;
        Moralis.User.currentAsync().then(function (user) {
            wallet = user.get('ethAddress');
            
        });
return wallet;
    }
```